# How can I programmatically get a list of all of the Sitecore domains in a site?

Tags: security, sitecore, membership-provider, sitecore7.5

In Sitecore 7.5 I would like to be able to get a list of all of the current Sitecore domains in code. I know that Sitecore security is simply built on top of the ASP.NET Membership Provider, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to get a list of all of the domains in code.

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `GetDomains()` method in `Sitecore.SecurityModel.DomainManager` class:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Gets all domains handled by the current provider.
/// </summary>
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Domain> GetDomains()
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Seemed like a simple thing, but I couldn't find any documentation for it anywhere.

Comment: I think, this only gets it for the default provider. Sitecore allows you to "chain" in multiple providers.

Comment: @MarkCassidy most probably you're right. Corey, if you use more than 1 provider, you may need to dig a little bit deeper.